# how to remove auto indexing in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How to remove auto indexing in `pandas` dataframe? drop index does not work.
So when I used `df.iloc[0:4]['col name']`, it always returns two-column, one for the actual data that I need, one for the auto row index. How could I get rid of the auto indexing and only return the column that I need?

This is what `iloc[0:4]['col name']` returns :

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | id2 |
| 1 | id2 |
| 2 | id1 |
| 3 | id3 |

and below is what I actually want :

|  |
| --- |
| id2 |
| id2 |
| id1 |
| id3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work in JupyterLab / Jupyter Notebook, use the command

```
iloc[0:4]['col name'].style.hide_index()
```

---

*The explanation:*

Dataframes **always** have an index, and there is no way of how to remove it, because it is a *core part* of every dataframe.

(`iloc[0:4]['col name']` is a dataframe, too.)

You can only *hide* it in your output.

For example in JupyterLab (or Jupyter Notebook) you may display your dataframe (`df`) without index using the command

```
df.style.hide_index()          # in your case: iloc[0:4]['col name'].style.hide_index()
```

Be careful - `df.style.hide_index()` is NOT a dataframe (it is a `Styler` object), so don't assign it back to `df`:

```
        # df = df.style.hide_index()       # Don't do it, never!
```

---

An example of a dataframe output — at first with the index, then without it:

[image]